# Next 13 doesnt build correct

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

Hy, the problem is when i want to build next in host , next never finishes building

```bash
- info Creating an optimized production build
- info Compiled successfully
- info Linting and checking validity of types
- info Collecting page data
[  ==] - info Generating static pages (0/16)Killed
```

however it when i run npm start , site loads but the css file is not complete.

I have tried to run npm run build manually but i got the same result

Edit:The problem is when i try to build Cpu and memory usage goes 100% and i think os kills building. How can i fix that?

Comment: What operating system are you using and what are the specs for CPU and memory on the machine you are using? Also if you have a antivirus installed I recommend putting NodeJS on the allow list.